# expss can not reproduce results of tab_last_sig_cpct with prop.test

Tags: r, expss

Lately I have been experimenting with the great expss package. Somehow I can't reproduce the results of tb_last_sig_cpct when I use the underlying prop.test function.

The result of prop.test gives a significant difference and tab_last_sig_cpct gives no significant difference. Am I doing something wrong?

```
dataset %>%
   tab_cells(X1, X2) %>%
   tab_cols(total(), X3, X4) %>%   
   tab_stat_cases(label = "N", total_row_position = "above") %>%
   tab_stat_cpct(label="%", total_statistic = "w_cpct", total_label = "#Total cases") %>%
   tab_last_sig_cpct() %>%
   tab_pivot(stat_position = "inside_columns") %>%
   drop_empty_rows() %>%
   drop_empty_columns()
```

[Output of expss package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CB6MR.png)
[prop.test result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bQFy.png)

Comment: expss utilizes the base in same columns as percent. In your case it is 100 for both groups. That's why the difference.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Now it works when using:
`prop.test(x = c(0.4, 0.51), n = c(100, 100), correct = F)`

Comment: Please, note, that for  significance we need cases base, not percent, as in the table. In your case `prop.test` gives correct result contrary to expss. And, if you insist on this table format, you need some workarounds to get correct significance

Comment: Yes, if I understand you correctly, my code with 100 for both groups replicates the behavior of expss. Which means that in the context of my custom table, using tab_last_sig_cpct makes no sense. But doing a workaround with cases base I imagine is not so easy.